# Node.js/Socket.io: process.env.port gives error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
```

and later:

```
socket = io.listen(port)
```

then on:

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', ...)
```

I get the error:

TyoeError: server.on is not a function on socket.io/lib/manager.js:104

```
server.on('error, function(err) {
       ^
```

But if I set:

```
var port = 1337;
```

It works fine. How do I fix so it works with process.env.port?

Comment: Please show more of your code, especially how the `server` variable is set.

Comment: I dont have a server-variable. Thats from socket.io/lib/manger.js which is part of the node-module. Basically the code that I provided is all the code creating the error.

Comment: What is the value of the `port` variable? Maybe it must be a number and not a string as it comes from the environment variable - then you could try `var port = Number(process.env.port) || 1337;`.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks.

Comment: Great; I converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the socket library doesn't expect the port to be a string (which it will be when coming from an environment variable).

Try converting it to a number first:

```
var port = Number(process.env.port) || 1337;
```